# Can I use \begingroup \endgroup as delimiter of \detokenize, instead of {}?

Tags: braces, detokenize

I would like to use other delimiters than `{}` for the argument of `\detokenize`. E.g. something like

```
\detokenize\begingroup a lot of stuff \com \mycom \endgroup
```

but it does not work. Am I really obliged to use curly braces ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because i would like to start the capture (`\detokenize\begingroup`) at some point, initiated by some command, and make it stop (`\endgroup`) in another command.

Comment: once you start `\detokenize` commands are not expanded until the closing brace is seen so even if `\egroup` worked you would not be able to have the `\egroup` inside another definition. You indicate in comments that you want to write to a file in which case you don't need detokenize at all just something like filecontents package to write the contents of an environment verbatim

Comment: I think filecontents packages is not suitable for me, because I need to do several things on my content before i `\write` it to the file.

Comment: @nicolasroy As I said below my answer, I think it would be useful to ask a question which explains the entire context here. There may be alternative approaches which make sense if we know what is actually required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TeX will allow you to use implicit `{` and `}` tokens in some places: these are available as `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. The `\detokenize` primitive is toks-like, and so will accept an implicit begin-group token

```
\detokenize\bgroup stuff}
\bye
```

but requires an explicit end-group token (as shown).

`\begingroup`/`\endgroup` forms a 'semi-simple' group, which is not the same group type as formed by `{`/`}`. The two types are thus not interchangeable.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. But it does help for my problem, since I can't use `\detokenize\bgroup stuff \egroup`, because the end `}` is mandatory, if I understood correctly. Right ?

Comment: @nicolasroy As I've indicated, you do need an explicit `}`, in the same way you do with a toks assignment (and in contrast to boxes, which do allow an implicit end-group token). You probably will need to do a verbatim-like grab.

Comment: Yes, I will look at verbatim. But I want to `\write` the result of this grab into a file, and need therefore an "expandable verbatim", if it exists...

Comment: @nicolasroy I think a question which actually explains what you need to do would be helpful: it's difficult to give more information with the bits-and-pieces here!